# android layout margins with percentage

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to set margins by percentage.. I have 4 imageviews in a linearlayout and want to set default left,right,top,bottom margins that keep same percentage for each screen size.

is it possible ?

here is a demo what i want..
[image]

And here is what i've tried and doesn't work

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <Thumbnail
            android:id="@+id/thumb1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4" />

        <Thumbnail
            android:id="@+id/thumb2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="10" >

         <Thumbnail
             android:id="@+id/thumb3"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="4" >
         </Thumbnail>

        <Thumbnail
            android:id="@+id/thumb4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can have invisible `View`s in your `LinearLayout`s as spacers and use the `layout_weight` mechanism to assign them relative size.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Thumbnail
        android:id="@+id/thumb1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <Thumbnail
        android:id="@+id/thumb2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: logical if there isn't any other way :) but not sure with memory usage because i need so much invisible views

Comment: There is a `<Space>` view for that. I don't think there will be any performance/memory penalty for using invisible `View` instead, but really not sure - `View.java` is huge, skimmed it for just several minutes.

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov `Space` was added in API level 14 so it's not as useful. Its naming makes the purpose more evident though.

Comment: there is  `android.support.v7.widget.Space`. Though that could be an extra dependency.

Comment: android.support.v7.widget.Space is deprecated. Use android.support.v4.widget.Space instead.

Answer (score 22):

**Added on Aug 1 2017:**

The two layouts from this answer are now deprecated but there is a description provided there on how to get the same functionality with `ConstraintLayout`. Thanks to [dpg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1623598/dpg) for pointing this out.

If you plan on using the percentages with resources, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345082/android-constraintlayout-percentage-using-dimens) might be useful.

---

**Old answer:**

There is now a better way that came out with support library version 23.0.0 (about time, right?). You can now use [PercentFrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html) or [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html). They both have the following attributes:

- layout_widthPercent
- layout_heightPercent
- layout_marginPercent
- layout_marginLeftPercent
- layout_marginTopPercent
- layout_marginRightPercent
- layout_marginBottomPercent
- layout_marginStartPercent
- layout_marginEndPercent

You can also take a look at [PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutParams.html)

Comment: Is this only for Android 6 ?

Comment: The percent layouts are in the Percent Support Library, which means that they are not only for Android 6.

Comment: The new better way has become deprecated now. For both Layouts on the links:
`This class was deprecated in API level 26.0.0-beta1.
consider using ConstraintLayout and associated layouts instead.`

Comment: Perhaps you mean ConstraintLayout in "...how to get the same functionality with CoordinatorLayout..."?

Answer (score 16):

You can set margins with percentage using [ConstraintLayout's Guidelines](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7#4511).

Say you want to define following percentage values for your layout:

[image: Requested percentage values]

Then you simply add following guidelines to your layout:

[image: Layout Editor]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/verGuideline1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/verGuideline2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/verGuideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/verGuideline4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/verGuideline1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/verGuideline2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/verGuideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/verGuideline4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horGuideline4" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/verGuideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/verGuideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/verGuideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/verGuideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horGuideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.12" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horGuideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.47" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horGuideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.53" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horGuideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.88" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As a result your layout looks something like this:

[image: Result view]

Comment: Cool ! I didn't know about this. Also, `android.support.constraint.Guideline` has ben replaced with `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your image here is what you could possibly do, use a relative layout and put the linear layout inside it. you can also use the weightSum if you want to make the image views to fit properly.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: giving exact margin is not good way for multiple screens. that's why i'm looking for a percentege solution

Comment: Setting a left and right margins for your relative layout will set same margins on all screens since these values are in dp.

Comment: but dp values effects different for each density.

Comment: These are density-independent pixels, in my experience using dp units in layouts has caused no issues in terms of margins on different screens.