# Android: Position by percentage?

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout, scaling, percentage

I have a UI Design from my designer, and it exists of a background map with several buttons on it, positioned non-linear all over the map. Currently I position them in a `RelativeLayout` that is as large as the map, and use `margin-left` and `margin-top` etc in `dip`.

This works ok, but I also need to account for users with very small screens, that cause the map to scale down. My relative layout scales with it, but the margin values ofcourse not.

So I am wondering, how should I do this? I would prefer to layout these buttons using percentages like

```
left="30%"
top="50%"
```

Is there anything in Android that makes such a thing possible? Otherwise I have to come up with a custom layout class for that.

Visual Representation: (Ofcourse they don't actually are on 6 lines, and partially overlap in x or y position). It's actually a real (abstract) map of a building with location markers that you can press as buttons.

```
 -------------------------
 |    x              x   |
 |           x           |
 |                       |
 |      x                |
 |                 x     |
 |           x          x|
 -------------------------
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or some visual representation of what you want? (And yes, you may have to resort to a writing a custom ViewGroup class)

Comment: @Karakuri I did add a ascii art example.

Comment: what did you end up with using for this? I need to implement something similar. any hint would be helpful. thanks

Comment: Since we used a fixed image as map, I just used relative positioning with margin-xxx set to correct DP values inside a fixed size (matching image) relative-layout.

Comment: Now it's possible with percentage Guideline, take a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200716/android-layout-margins-with-percentage/47134315#47134315

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complicated way that does not require a custom ViewGroup. Suppose you want a button at left 30%, top 40%

```
FrameLayout 
   View with background, match parent
   LinearLayout orientation=horizontal, match parent 
     View layout_width=0dp, layout_weight=30, height=match_parent
     LinearLayout orientation=vertical, width=0dp, weight=70, hieght=match
       View layout_height=0dp, layout_weight=40, width=match_parent
       FrameLayout layout_height=0dp, layout_weight=60
         Button
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `Dimension` resource files put in the relevant layout- buckets so I can change margins/paddings/sizes depending on device size.

(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

([Storing dimensions in xml file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885164/storing-dimensions-in-xml-file-in-android))

Comment: Hmm, that won't do it I am afraid. I know the technique, but I really have to have something more dynamique.

Comment: @Peterdk There's no XML support for percentages AFAIK. You could do it in code. Does that do it?

Comment: Alternatively you could use LinearLayouts exclusively and layout_weights but I feel this will be restrictive to your designs. See here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4961467/833647)

Comment: Well, wat I think I'll do then is to build a custom layout class that recalculates the margin's for each object based on a detected scale or so. - Yes layout_weights would also be an option, however they all differ in `x` and `y` position, so I don't think you can pull that off with `LinearLayout`'s