# Android - ConstraintLayout percentage using dimens

Tags: android, android-resources, percentage, dimension, android-constraintlayout

There is a question [How to make ConstraintLayout work with percentage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318228/how-to-make-constraintlayout-work-with-percentage-values) and its answers show how to use the percentages:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
```

But if you don't want to hardcode the percentage but use a dimen resource it does not work.

```
<!-- inside the layout -->

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@dimen/guideline_perc"/>

<!-- inside dimens.xml -->

<dimen name="guideline_perc>0.5</dimen>
```

You get the following error:

`Float types not allowed (at 'guideline_perc' with value 0.5).`

If you replace the value with 1, a similar error is returned:

`Integer types not allowed (at 'guideline_perc' with value 1).`

How do you set a percentage without hardcoding the value into the layout?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using a dimen resource, use an item resource of type dimen:

`<item name="guideline_perc" type="dimen">0.5</item>`

If using integers, an `integer` resource would work best:

`<integer name="guideline_perc">1</integer>`

Comment: If this works, then that's either an IDE bug or a build tools bug, as both approaches result in a dimension resource.

Comment: Defining a resource as a dimen requires a unit of measure. Defining it as an item with the type `dimen` does not. Additionally a format `float` could be added but it is not necessary.

Comment: Ah, I see. Try using a `float` or `integer` resource, then, rather than `dimen`.

Comment: Using `integer` would be a better solution, that's true, but in this example I was using a float and there isn't a `float` resource afaik.

Comment: Hmmm... I could have sworn that there were `float` resources, though I am not seeing them in the docs right now...

Comment: Are you thinking of `fraction`? E.g., `<fraction name="guideline_perc">0.67</fraction>`. Used like `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@fraction/guideline_perc"`

Comment: Nvm, that doesn't work. AS doesn't complain, and the layout even looks right in the preview, but it won't compile. Need to use this: `<item name="guideline_perc" type="dimen" format="float">0.67</item>
`

Comment: hwo do I reference this?

Answer (score 13):

To set a percentage use the fraction syntax

```
<fraction name="guideline_perc">0.5</fraction>
```

and then

```
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@fraction/guideline_perc"
```

Comment: Small point of note: Confusingly, the XML editor does NOT offer _typeAhead_. Red light goes off only when you correctly spell the resource name in full.

Answer (score 1):

Now in 2021 dimen float works fine. Just autocompletion in Android studio in that case doesn't. Don't know why.

`app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@dimen/guideline_perc"`

Answer (score 0):

Generated by the system itself

```html
<item name="porcent_line_top_navebar" type="dimen" format="float">0.88</item>
```